# why was content height of UIWebView not change with rotation

Tags: uiwebview

Why does the content height of my UIWebView not change with rotation?

From Portrait to Landscape, the content width should expand and the content height should shrink.  It does visually as it should, but not according to my NSLog.

Critical added info about my UIView.

1) my UIWebView is not the whole UIView, but a sub-view of my overall UIView.

2) with the first-swipe through my code, I change the frame.size.height of the UIWebView to the UIWebView's contentHeight via:

```
UIScrollView *scrollViewInsideWebView = [[webView_ subviews] lastObject];
webViewContentHeight = scrollViewInsideWebView.contentSize.height;
```

Okay, we then push our UIButton below it ... everything works as it should with Portrait.

Then I rotate it to Landscape and the above webViewContentHeight does not change at all.  And, of course, the UIButton stays pushed way down where it was in Portrait with a tall(er) webViewContentHeight.

???

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at my "Safari like" browser implementation here : https://github.com/sylverb/CIALBrowser

Basically, make sure that all the autoresizing masks are ok ! For my example with a toolbar and an UIWebView, I have

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

toolBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin; // for a toolbar at the top of the view
toolBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin; // for a toolbar at the bottom of the view
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: My autoresizing masks look like:

Comment: Whoops - hit return too quickly - anyway, set top strut and set the two springs - problem solved and thanks bunches.  As a matter of fact, my only remaining problem is to design those cursed @2X, etc. graphics.  I use GraphicConverter in a very simple way and it does well for Web Page design, very well. But all these 30px, 57px stuff - I'm going into unchartered territory for me, at least.